# what should I put in the views.py so that a specific user can add new complaints in a complaint management system

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have the model created for complaints. I tried a few methods to help a user create the complaint, but nothing works so I have given up and I just want to understand what to add in the views.py so that I can do that. The system basically has multiple users and I want the users to send in their complaints to the admin panel, so that they can be viewed, edited or deleted as per use on the dashboard. Right now my form does get created but it does not save the complaints in the admin panel.

models.py:

```
class Complaints(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= CASCADE, null = True, blank=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
description = models.TextField(null=True, blank= True)
highpriority = models.BooleanField(default=False)
document = models.FileField(upload_to='static/documents')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

what to add in the views.py? I've tried various things but I don't know what to do to make it work.

this if my views.py but I feel like the entire thing is wrong so I want an entirely new views:

```
class ComplaintCreate(CreateView):
    model = Complaints
    form = ComplaintForm
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('New')
    template_name = 'new.html'
```

I want the final page to look like this:

[image]

Comment: I think if you didn't imported `CASCADE` from `models` this line `user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= CASCADE, null = True, blank=True)` won't works as an expected it should look like this `user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null = True, blank=True)`

Answer (score 1):

there is not form attribute in CreateView change `form` to `form_class`

```
class ComplaintCreate(CreateView):
    model = Complaints
    form_class = ComplaintForm
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('New')
    template_name = 'new.html'
```

Comment: ohk... is there anything else I should add in my views.py??

Comment: your view works now? 
Do you want to add a request user for Complaints ?